# problem inheriting from list

Tags: python, class, object

```
class speciallist(list):

    def __new__(self): 
        return self

    def custommethod(self,param):
         #do stuff
         return value

listesp = speciallist()
listesp.custommethod(param)
```

I get "unbound method custommethod() must be called with speciallist instance as first argument"

I thought it was going to call the method from the class, why does it do this?

Answer (score 5):

That's a sneaky one. Short answer, remove the `__new__` method from your definition.

The [`__new__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is a class method, so it takes the *class*, not the instance, as its first argument. It's designed to create an instance (possibly of another class) and return it. You're simply returning the class itself, not an instance of it. Python lets you call `custommethod` from there, but it's not bound to an instance, so it doesn't automatically get `self` inserted as the first argument.

To set up an instance, use the `__init__` method (which takes `self` as its first argument, but returns nothing).